# Can MetalFX scalers support textures with alpha?

Tags: ios, metal

I'm trying to upscale a texture using MetalFX's `MTLFXSpatialScaler`. The input texture has transparency (it's `rgba8Unorm`) but in the scaled texture, the transparency has been removed so that previous transparent areas are now rendered as black.

I've confirmed that the scaler's output texture is also `rgba8Unorm`. Also to confirm this isn't a problem drawing the scaled textures, I used the Metal debug tools to inspect each texture. Here's a pixel from the alpha part of the input texture:

[image: Input texture with alpha]

And here's a pixel from the same area in the scaled output (notice how the A is now 1):

[image: Scaled texture with alpha = 1]

Does `MTLFXSpatialScaler` or `MTLFXTemporalScaler` support scaling a texture with alpha? Is there some additional setting or pixel for I need to use to enable this?